# Determining the limit of a function by simplifying it based in its order

Tags: limits

Suppose a function $f(x)=e^{-0.4x}\cdot(x^4-4x^2+2)$.

If I try to determine $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$, I can do so by always simplifying $f(x)$ according to its order by saying something like:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^{-0.4x}\cdot(x^4-4x^2+2) \\
=&\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}\cdot x^4 \\
=&\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^{-x} \\
=&\space0
\end{align*}
$$
Is this equation a mathematically correct way to represent the process?

If not, how else could I accomplish this using mathematical expressions without resorting to phrasing normal sentences?

Comment: [Perhaps helpful?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't, but you can fix it by using this property of limits:

$$\lim f(x)\cdot g(x) = \lim f(x) \cdot \lim g(x)$$

if both limits exist. In this case, that would mean

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-0.4x}\cdot(x^4-4x^2+2) = \lim_{x\to\infty}x^4e^{-0.4x}\cdot\left(1-\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$

$$= \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x^4e^{-0.4x}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}1-\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)= 0 \cdot 1 = 0$$

For the last step where you "removed" the polynomial altogether, that can't be fixed like the other step. You would just have to use the fact that exponentials "outweigh" or "outspeed" polynomials.